# Erro no Marker do Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou tentando colocar uma marca na mapa e está dando um erro de `NullPointExeption`

Segue o método:

```
private void setMapaGoogle() {
    if (mapa != null) {
        mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        try{
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            **mapa = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true)).getMap();**
            mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlng)
                    .title("Onde Estou!")
                    .snippet("")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mark_mapa_local_atual))
                    .visible(true));
            // Move a camera para a posição.
            mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),14));
            //Efeito na camera do mapa
            mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
            mapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            mapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
            mapa.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           StringBuilder sb = new  StringBuilder().append(e.getClass().getSimpleName()); 
           if  (e.getMessage() != null) { 
               sb.append("\n"); 
               sb.append(e.getMessage()); 
           } 
           Log.e("Exeção", sb.toString()); 
           aux = sb.toString();
           // this code write out all message
           Log.e("Exeção","setMapaGoogle", e);
       }
    }else{
        setMapaGoogle();
    }
}
```

O erro ocorre na linha:

```
mapa = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true)).getMap();
```

Comment: Seria bom se você realçasse a linha onde o erro de nullPointerException ocorre, para q as pessoas possam lhe ajudar mais facilmente.

Comment: Opa, foi malz ae. O erro ta na linha: mapa = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true)).getMap();

Comment: Quando eu tiro essa linha o sistema roda numa boa, só queria entender melhor para que ela serve, já que esse trecho eu peguei direto do site do Google e lá não encontrei detalhes sobre essa linha em especial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível que isso aconteça porque no teu ficheiro XML tens:

> android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

muda no java de

```
 mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

para

```
 mapa = ((**MapFragment**) **getFragmentManager**().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

(sem os **)

ou então no xml de

> android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

para

> android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

tens que ter atenção ao referenciar algo. Diz algo se ajudei e se é mesmo este o erro :)
Se não for tenta colocar aqui o logcat e o ficheiro xml também!

Cumps